# Oracle 12 : get data from another stored procedure and use into FOR x IN (....)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

"query" is string variable and I am appending result by executing following.

```
FOR X IN
        (SELECT Years FROM School_Years)
        LOOP
            query := query || x.Year || ',' ;            
        END LOOP;
```

My question: 
I already have stored procedure (GetSchoolYears) "SELECT Years FROM School_Years".

Instead of "SELECT Years FROM School_Years", how can I use stored procedure name? Something like......

```
FOR X IN
        (GetSchoolYears)
        LOOP
            query := query || x.Year || ',' ;            
        END LOOP;
```

or any other idea to use result of that stored procedure within IN (---)

Comment: This code doesn't even compile with `Option Strict On`. And it throws a runtime exception otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out quotes and added two you didn't need. Try this:

```
Dim str as String = "I am" & firstName & "-" & lastname
```

Comment: And further: try `Dim str as String = String.Format("I am {0} - {1}", firstName, lastName)`